# Formas de obter valores do banco com ResultSet

Tags: java, query, jdbc

Formas de obter valores do banco de dados em Java (JDBC).

```
 public static Connection getConnection(){
        /* 1. Faz a conexao com a base de dados */
        /* 2. Retorna qual banco ira trabalhar */

        Connection connection=null;

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/base", "postgres", "postgres");
            System.out.print("Conexao com o banco de dados efetuada com sucesso!");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.print("Erro durante a conexao com o banco de dados!");
        }

        return connection;
    }
```

---

```
Map<String,String> fields_values = new HashMap<String,String>(); // Chave: Valor

String sql = "SELECT id, nome, idade, endereco FROM PESSOA";

Connection conexao = getConnection(); // Chama método para retornar conexão com o banco
prepared = conexao.prepareStatement(sql); // Prepara o SQL para ser executado no banco

ResultSet result = prepared.executeQuery(sql); // Retorno do banco de dados
```

Acredito que deve existir outra maneira de pegar os valores do banco de dados sem ter que usar métodos como `result.getInt(), result.()getString, result.getFloat()`.

1. Eu conseguiria obter os valores do banco de dados de outra forma?
2. Consigo obter os valores de uma forma mais simplificada para armazenar na variavel `fields_values`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, você pode recuperar [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) do [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) e usando [`getColumnCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnCount--) você recuperaria a quantidade de colunas para depois recuperar os valores do `ResultSet` pela posição da coluna.

Para recuperar o `ResultSetMetaData` e a quantidade de colunas você deve fazer desta forma:

Como você está usando um mapa de *strings* para armazenar os valores uma forma de valores seria esta:

```
final ResultSetMetaData metaRS = rs.getMetaData();
final int columnCount = metaRS.getColumnCount();
```

Depois teremos que recuperar todas os valores das colunas como um `Object` e chamar `toString` dele, pois pode ser que não saibamos exatamente o tipo de dados no banco. Como não temos o nome também, iremos pegar pelo indíce, algo desta forma:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        final Object value = rs.getObject(i);
        fieldsValues.put(metaRS.getColumnName(i), value.toString());
    }
}
```

Caso você queira imprimir os valores do seu mapa para verificar se estão *OK* você pode fazer algo desta forma:

```
final Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = fieldsValues.entrySet();
for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : entries) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Key: %s | Value: %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}
```

Que irá gerar algo assim:

```
Key: id | Value: 1
Key: idade | Value: 25
Key: nome | Value: Nome 1
Key: endereco | Value: Endereco 1
```

Note também que neste caso só é possível armazernar para uma linha, já que sempre irá sobrescrever os valores do seu mapa.

Um exemplo completo seria este:

```
final Map<String, String> fieldsValues = new HashMap<>();

final Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/base", "postgres", "postgres");
final String sql = "SELECT id, nome, idade, endereco FROM PESSOA";
final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
final ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

final ResultSetMetaData metaRS = rs.getMetaData();
final int columnCount = metaRS.getColumnCount();

while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        final Object value = rs.getObject(i);
        fieldsValues.put(metaRS.getColumnName(i), value.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito bom cara, testei aqui funcionou certinho!